# query return empty after adding .lower

Tags: python

Why my function  stop working after adding .lower function, in line 3

this is my code :

```
@action(methods=['get'], detail=False)
    def filter(self, request, pk=None):
        search = request.query_params.get('search').lower()
        queryset = Contact.objects.all().filter(
            Q(first_name=search) | Q(city=search) | Q(country=search) |
            Q(last_name=search) | Q(email=search) | Q(company=search)
        )
        serializer = ContactSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Plz provide more info than 'stop working', you getting a traceback?

Comment: @ΕυάγγελοςΓρηγορόπουλος  when i use .lower  i get no result 
 i get only []  like that empty

Comment: It means that there are no objects with the value in  `search` variable in your model.

Comment: yes i have, and it works fine after removing .lower

Comment: i have two  rows 
  first_name = Amine
  last_name = Ricardo

Comment: it work fine after changing my database values from Amine to amine

Comment: i think the issue in Q function

Comment: Q function is case sensitive, i'm still looking for the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding `__icontains`   `first_name__icontains`